# Yandex API to translate PDF and return translated PDF?

Tags: google-translate, translate, yandex

I have used the yandex translate api to translate strings and it works just fine, just wanted to confirm if there is any way to send a pdf file with the post request and in response get a pdf file or html, like in the demo ? [Yandex Translate API](https://translate.yandex.com/doc) OR does the google translate api support document files [this link suggests that it is not supported yet.](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-translate-api/9_ZAWwc3nPs)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! well.. we did not use the yandex api, instead we used python pdfkit to convert the pdf to html, (css, html, images and js separately), then used the google tranlate api post call to translate the html and convert that back to pdf.